# Identifying one-to-many relationship

Tags: database, database-design

I have some questions about meanings of identifying one to many relationship. I read some other related questions on stack overflow, but I need a bit more information :)

Lets suppose we have table "Country" and table "Cities". It seems to me that this is example of one-to-many identifying relationship. But when I use MySql Workbench to create one-to-many identifying relationship between these two tables I get the following:

```
Countries
---------
country_id (PK)
...

Cities
--------
city_id    (PK)
country_id (PK)
...
```

We have composite primary key in Cities table, and it will allow following rows in that table (lets assume country_id and city_id are strings for better readability):

```
1) France, Paris
2) England, London
3) England, Manchester
4) France, London
```

In order to have it correct way, we need to put UNIQUE constraint on city_id, so that it can belong to only one country. But isn't it more clear then to just make country_id as NOT_NULL (FK) in Cities table and get the same effect:

```
Cities
---------
city_id (PK)
country_id (FK) (NOT_NULL)
```

So, is this identifying or non identifying relationship? Seems to me that it is "logically identifying", but by definition it is non-identifying, since parent PK is not part of child PK. It is a bit confusing :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the key of cities is (country_id, city_id) then the relationship is "identifying" - meaning that the primary key is partly or wholly a foreign key reference to another table. If country_id is not part of the primary key then it is non-identifying.

Those two different keys would make the table represent very different things in each case but only you can say which better fits your requirements.

Don't worry too much about the concept of identifying vs non-identifying relationships. It is a concept that originates in ER modelling but in relational database design it is usually of very little practical importance.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But what if (country_id, city_id) is the primary key of "Cities" table, and city_id column is additionally set as unique. Wouldn't that solution technically be the same as my last solution when I have city_id as primary key and country_id as foreign key? So I would have two equivalent solutions, one with identifying and one with non identifying relationship?

Comment: If city_id has a uniqueness constraint on it then (country_id, city_id) cannot be "the primary key" because primary keys are by definition irreducible. Nor do I see why you would want uniquness constraints on both (country_id, city_id) and (city_id). What would that achieve?

Comment: It would achieve following: one country can have multiple cities, but one city can belong to only one country. If I omit unique constraint from city_id then: one country can have multiple cities, but city also can belong to multiple countries. Table counties contains all countries in the world. Table cities contains all cities in the world. So I need a way to specify in table cities to which country belongs particular city. I can do that in two ways: a) identifying relationship where city_id is additionally set as unique, or b) city_id is primary key, and country_id is just foreign key.

Comment: In both cases the uniqueness constraint on (country_id, city_id) is redundant. Drop it and just make city_id unique.

Comment: In case b) there is no uniqueness constraint on (country_id, city_id). Primary key is city_id, so it is unique by default, and country_id is just foreign_key, so it is not unique :) But that's solution, so I think case is closed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You have in your own example data the counter-argument for your suggestion.  `London` appears as a city in both England and France, but they are not the same city;  The city is identified not by it's `city_id`, which is the name of the city, but by the pair `country_id`, `city_id`.  There's no other natural key for this kind of data.  If you wanted a single column primary key, you would be forced to invent a surrogate key to act as the primary key (say, an autoincremented Integer)

Comment: I think I understand now. So, child table in identifying relationship does not make sense if we don't know the parent key? In other words, if we have no info about parent, child can't be identified by any means, because of incomplete information :) So, identifying/non-identifying relationships are just abstract concepts, and we can use both of them to get the same solution (as I explained in reply to dportas)?

Comment: I forgot to say, that in my mind city_id is complete identifier for any city in the world, so it has properties of surrogate key and can be treated as one. That is why I said (France, London) is incorrect row, and that city_id must be set as unique column.

Answer (score 2):

By definition an identifying relationship uses the primary key of the referenced record.

Your last solution looks like the one you need. But it's no identifying relation.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was the case, but it's always better to ask :)